# How to hide values in iOS-charts PieCharts?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I'm trying to change a PieChartView to not show the values on the Chart.
Indeed I'm looking to a similar function to

`pieChartView.drawSliceTextEnabled = false`

but just for the values.

I would be very thankful for some help :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

in data set, disable `drawValueEnabled` like `set.drawValuesEnabled = false`